# 2 approaches in exception handling

Tags: java, exception

In Java Language Specification 8 (JLS8) >>> Chapter 11: Exceptions ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html)), I saw that they are 2 two approaches for exception handling:

> Some programming languages and their implementations react to such errors by **peremptorily terminating the program**; other programming languages allow an implementation to react in an **arbitrary or unpredictable way**. Neither of these approaches is compatible with the design goals of the Java SE platform: to provide **portability** and robustness.

1st approach: peremptorily terminating the program
2nd approach: arbitrary or un-predictable way

But, I cannot distinguish clearly these 2 ways and what's the language will use they (what's language use 1st approach? what's language use 2nd approach?). Please help me to clarify this issue and give me an example to demonstrate

Moreover, the "portability" of Java, in this case, means what?

Comment: Heard about try-catch blocks and throws clause? 1st one continues and 2nd one terminates program

Comment: "arbitrary or unpredictable way" means what? @minigeek

Comment: Hard to guess what are you trying to say without code example

Comment: Are you asking for programming language examples that have _different_ exception handling semantics than Java?

Comment: yes @MickMnemonic..that is my question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about programming languages that **peremptorily terminate the program**, but it could be that early versions of `Pascal` handled the problem this way (reasoning that it's better to terminate the program than to introduce arbitrary errors into the result).

To react in an **arbitrary or unpredictably way**: consider what happens if a program written in `C` accesses an array outside of it's bounds: you get a buffer overflow. Buffer overflows are the base for many security problems (search for "buffer overflow attack").

---

Consider this simple `C` function:

```
int test(int arg) {
    int x;
    int arr[8];
    int y;
    x = 0; y = 0;
    arr[8] = 99;
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return x+y;
}
```

Executing this simple function could:

- print out "0 0"
- print out "99 0"
- print out "0 99"
- crash the program
- format your hard disk

A similar method written in `Java` will always throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Hmm...the 2nd explanation is difficult to understand :(...Can you explain more details?

Comment: @RichardHarold I've added an example on what will happen in `C`

Answer (score 0):

Peremptorily terminating the program = throwing a `NullPointerException` you can't catch (not that you ever should).

Allowing an implementation to react in an arbitrary or unpredictable way = not throwing a `NullPointerException` at all. There are languages that do just that (think sending a message to a `nil` object in Objective-C).

Comment: "allowing an implementation to react in an arbitrary or unpredictable way" means the program does not anything when an exception occurs, so that, in this case, the "not good thing" can occurs unpredictably (we can predict what will happens)...It's right?

Comment: That's exactly the idea